Is there a way to use replaceChildren() on looped elements when hovering over them?


const addToCartButtons =  document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart');
const products = document.getElementsByClassName('product');

const addToCartButtonsArray = Array.from(addToCartButtons);
const productsArray = Array.from(products);

const increment = document.createElement('img');
        increment.setAttribute('src', '/assets/images/icon-increment-quantity.svg');
        increment.style.zIndex = '0';
        increment.style.width = '15px';
        increment.style.marginBottom = '0.5px';
        increment.style.marginRight = '6px';
        increment.style.border = 'none';
        increment.style.cursor = 'pointer';

const decrement = document.createElement('img');
        decrement.setAttribute('src', '/assets/images/icon-decrement-quantity.svg');
        decrement.style.zIndex = '1';
        decrement.style.width = '15px';
        decrement.style.marginBottom = '0.5px';
        decrement.style.marginLeft = '6px';
        decrement.style.border = 'none';
        decrement.style.cursor = 'pointer';

const quantity = document.createElement('span');
        quantity.textContent = 0;

const addToCartButtonOnHover = document.createElement('div');
        addToCartButtonOnHover.classList.add('add-to-cart-on-hover');

addToCartButtonsArray.forEach(button => {
    
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {

        for (let i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++) {
                const element = productsArray[i].children[1];
                element.replaceChild(addToCartButtonOnHover, element.childNodes[0]);
        }

        addToCartButtonOnHover.append(decrement, quantity, increment);

        let count = 0;

        increment.onclick = function () {
            count += 1;
            quantity.textContent = count;
        }

        decrement.onclick = function () {
            count -= 1;
            quantity.textContent = count;
        }
    })

    
});
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.left-side {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: fit-content;
}

h1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.product {
    border: 1px solid green;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 43vh;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: -11%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.add-to-cart {
    border: 1px solid hsl(14, 65%, 9%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 16%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    line-height: 4.5vh;
    background-color: white;
}

.add-to-cart-on-hover {
    border: 1px solid hsl(14, 65%, 9%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: orange;
}

.product-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 25%;
}

.type-of-dessert {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    font-size: small;
    color: hsl(14, 25%, 72%)
}

.name-of-dessert {
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: large;
}

.price {
    color: hsl(14, 65%, 9%)
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="left-side">
        <h1>Desserts</h1>
        <div class="products">
            <div class="product">
                <img src="/assets/images/image-waffle-desktop.jpg" alt="An image showing waffles with strawberries on top">
                <div class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="type-of-dessert">Waffle</span>
                    <h3 class="name-of-dessert">Waffle with berries</h3>
                    <span class="price">$6.50</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img src="/assets/images/image-waffle-desktop.jpg" alt="An image showing waffles with strawberries on top">
                <div class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="type-of-dessert">Waffle</span>
                    <h3 class="name-of-dessert">Waffle with berries</h3>
                    <span class="price">$6.50</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="right-side">
        <div class="cart">
            <h2>Your cart(<span id="total-orders">0</span>)</h2>
            <img src="/assets/images/illustration-empty-cart.svg" alt="">
            <p>Your added items will appear here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>



I managed to loop through the class elements and replace the add-to-cart button with a new one using replaceChild() and childNodes[], but the problem is in the loop, when I hover one of them, instead of replacing the one that's hovered, it replaces the last one, and makes the rest white. Also I tried doing the same thing with forEach() but I don't think you can use it inside an eventListener?, because it wouldn't react to anything. I am trying to create a kind of shopping cart website, where you can increment the amount of articles when hovering over the button and add them to the cart, but I am currently stuck on this part. Also I can't classList.add the increment and decrement buttons so I have to style them manually, what's up with that?

when i run your code as the snippet, i get an error when hovering: ""Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'." I would start there to see about fixing your problem.

Your loop is very inefficient. You change the onclick on two elements for every mouseover. Instead you should delegate from the container
I strongly suggest you make your code DRYer and delegate the clicks
I would also consider not creating the increment/decrement on mouseover but just show/hide existing ones.
Anyway here is a delegation version using addEventlListener instead of onevent


function createButton(action, src) {
    const button = document.createElement('img'); // or a button with an image inside
    button.classList.add('quantity-control', action); // Add common class 'quantity-control' and specific action class
    button.setAttribute('src', src);
    button.style.width = '15px';
    button.style.marginBottom = '0.5px';
    button.style.border = 'none';
    button.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    // Adjust margin based on the action
    if (action === 'increment') {
        button.style.marginRight = '6px';
        button.style.zIndex = '0';
    } else if (action === 'decrement') {
        button.style.marginLeft = '6px';
        button.style.zIndex = '1';
    }

    return button;
}

// Function to create increment and decrement buttons
function createButtons() {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    const incrementButton = createButton('increment', '/assets/images/icon-increment-quantity.svg');
    const decrementButton = createButton('decrement', '/assets/images/icon-decrement-quantity.svg');
    container.appendChild(decrementButton);
    container.appendChild(incrementButton);
    return container;
}

// Event listener for products container
const productsContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
productsContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    const button = e.target.closest('.add-to-cart');
    if (!button) return; // Exit if not hovering over a button
    const productElement = button.closest('.product');
    const productInfoElement = productElement.querySelector('.product-info');
    // Clear any existing content in the product info section
    productInfoElement.innerHTML = '';
    // Create and append buttons with quantity span
    const buttonsContainer = createButtons();
    const quantity = document.createElement('span');
    quantity.textContent = 0;

    const addToCartButtonOnHover = document.createElement('div');
    addToCartButtonOnHover.classList.add('add-to-cart-on-hover');
    addToCartButtonOnHover.append(buttonsContainer, quantity);

    productInfoElement.appendChild(addToCartButtonOnHover);

    let count = 0;

    // Event delegation for increment and decrement buttons using a common class
    buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (!tgt.matches('.quantity-control')) return; // Is it a button?
        count = tgt.classList.contains('increment') ? count + 1 : Math.max(count - 1, 0);
        quantity.textContent = count;
    });
});
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.left-side {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: fit-content;
}

h1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.product {
    border: 1px solid green;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 43vh;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: -11%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.add-to-cart {
    border: 1px solid hsl(14, 65%, 9%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 16%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    line-height: 4.5vh;
    background-color: white;
}

.add-to-cart-on-hover {
    border: 1px solid hsl(14, 65%, 9%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -0.5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: orange;
}

.product-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 25%;
}

.type-of-dessert {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    font-size: small;
    color: hsl(14, 25%, 72%)
}

.name-of-dessert {
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: large;
}

.price {
    color: hsl(14, 65%, 9%)
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="left-side">
        <h1>Desserts</h1>
        <div class="products">
            <div class="product">
                <img src="/assets/images/image-waffle-desktop.jpg" alt="An image showing waffles with strawberries on top">
                <div class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="type-of-dessert">Waffle</span>
                    <h3 class="name-of-dessert">Waffle with berries</h3>
                    <span class="price">$6.50</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img src="/assets/images/image-waffle-desktop.jpg" alt="An image showing waffles with strawberries on top">
                <div class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="type-of-dessert">Waffle</span>
                    <h3 class="name-of-dessert">Waffle with berries</h3>
                    <span class="price">$6.50</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="right-side">
        <div class="cart">
            <h2>Your cart(<span id="total-orders">0</span>)</h2>
            <img src="/assets/images/illustration-empty-cart.svg" alt="">
            <p>Your added items will appear here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>



